# abort cancel leads to errors when used with %if%then%do in open code

Tags: sas

We run a main function which calls a lot of helper syntaxes and everything is run interactively out of the `EG SAS`. Usually one run takes 30 minutes or so so it's a good idea to stop the whole task when an error in the data shows up. For this, we have inside the main function some conditional `if-then` statements in `open code` (depending eg. on the year) and the `stop` is accomplished by an `abort cancel` statement.

It would look something like this **MWE**:

```
%let year = 2020;
%if &year. = 2020 %then %do;
data test;
x = 1; /*some condition which puts x = 1 if needed;*/ 
if x=1 then do; 
    put "There is an error, please check xy."; 
    abort cancel;
   /*%end;*/ 
end;
run;
%end;
```

This works like expected *except* with a second run of this code segment (or any `open code` segment containing `%if%then`) we will get two additional errors (not intended)

```
ERROR: Nesting of %IF statements in open code is not supported. %IF ignored.
ERROR: Skipping to next %END statement.
```

which makes sense, since the original `%if%then%do` was never ended by an `%end` statement.
Interestingly, this can be "fixed" by adding the `%end` to the `data test`.

While this hack works, I wonder if it breaks anything else or if there is a better solution to this. Any ideas?

Comment: which `%end` is your *hack*? The one after `run` or the one inside the comment ?

Comment: The one in the comment, which at least to me seems completely displaced there. Ofc I would need it to uncomment it before. Pretty strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how ready for prime time ABORT CANCEL really is. There is ABORT FILE option if your "helper files" are executed via %INCLUDE.

If your code is that complex it is probably worth the effort to create a macro.  Then you can use macro code to skip parts of the code and not cause the unexecuted open code %END issue.

```
%macro mystuff ;
%let status=OK;
....
%if &year. = 2020 %then %do;
data test;
  x = 1; /*some condition which puts x = 1 if needed;*/ 
  if x=1 then do; 
    put "There is an error, please check xy."; 
    call symputx('status','XY');
    abort ;
  end;
run;
%end;
%if "&status" ne "OK" %then %goto exit;

... another step that might change STATUS ...
%if "&status" ne "OK" %then %goto exit;

%exit:
%put &=status;
%mend ;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! And yes, most of the stuff is added gradually via ``%include``. I'll give the ``abort file`` a try but probably you're right and we should just wrap everything in a macro. I was just surprised that adding an ``%end`` was "working" but I guess this is just an inconsistency.